# Click element, hold Shift key and click another element in robotframework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I need to be able to click an element on a webpage and hold the Shift key on keyboard and press another element.

Can I implement this behaviour using "Press Key" in Selenium2Library?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve your scenario using AutoItLibrary

First you need to install win32com.client, use below command

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Then use AutoItLibrary command like as per your requirement
Send | {SHIFTDOWN}

For more info visit [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use using Pyautogui library. This library simulates the User Actions on GUI such as Mouse Control, Keyboards inputs,etc. You can find details at
 https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjN1ZbrocrSAhWIFJQKHXbiBGcQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpyautogui.readthedocs.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNEe5LY5eMdaquVD421_u-mpoFUOYQ&sig2=Lj-e4YldvbLNEvPe4NFHrA

Also U can install this library using pip by following keywords in  following docs

http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: Thanks. I have been able to press and hold "shift" key using pyautogui. However, I am having problem identifying the element using it. It seems that you can only specify absolute coordinates (x,y) using pyautogui. Is there a way to click an element in a webpage and then hold the shift key?

Also, "Mouse Over" keyword in Selenium2Library just simulates hovering of the cursor, it doesn't physically move the cursor. So I can't use that either. Any ideas?

Comment: You can first identify element and then use pyautogui library to enter text.